# Send text of a LI element in to a text input

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom-events

Getting the data from mySql is easy, but after getting the list of items, I've been trying to get togheter a function to click on any of the list items to send the text up to the value of the input... Heres what I have after a couple of days of trying.

```
// AJAX Request to cityes database
function buscarCiudades(str) {
  var respuestas = document.getElementById('sugerencias');
  if (str.length == 0) {
    respuestas.innerHTML = "";
    respuestas.setAttribute("style", "display:none;border:none;outline:none;");
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        respuestas.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        respuestas.setAttribute("style","display: block;border-top: 1px solid #272C33;border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;padding: 10px;");
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/editor/queries/paises.php?ciudad=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }

}

// my final effort to achive sending the content to a input field

var items = document.querySelectorAll("#sugerencias li");
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
  {
    items[i].onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('campomx').value = this.innerHTML;
    };
  }
```

Hense the two html elements in the dynamic process

```
  <input type="search" class="searchBox" name="ciudad" id="campomx" placeholder="Escribe el nombre del destino" onkeyup="buscarCiudades(this.value)" for="sugerencias">

  <ul id="sugerencias" class="sugerencias">
  </ul>
```

And this is the query structure:

```
$ciudad = htmlentities( $_GET['ciudad'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' );
$pq     = $dcon
  ->query( "
    SELECT *
    FROM ciudades
    WHERE ciudad LIKE '%$ciudad%'
    ORDER BY ciudad
    ASC LIMIT 10" );

 while ( $pr = $pq->fetch() )
 {
    echo $ciudadx = '<li>' . $pr['ciudad'] . ', ' . $pr['estado']. ", " . $pr['pais'] . '</li>';
 }
```

Could it be that the function doesn't fire up because it needs to load a pre-existent list? And if so... HOW????

Comment: I took your code without the AJAX and it works. What is inside your list and what part is not working?

Comment: That's precisely the problem I have, If I fill the UL manually, the Query-Selector works
But when the UL is dynamically populated, then the Query-Selector doesn't respond.

Comment: You are using `respuestas` to fill. Can you share its structure?

Comment: I've updated the question with the sql part.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the querySelector was loading before the list got populated.

My solution was to put the querySelector inside the onreadystatechange function after the response itself. like so...

```
    // AJAX Request to cityes database
    function buscarCiudades(str) {
      var respuestas = document.getElementById('sugerencias');
      if (str.length == 0) {
        respuestas.innerHTML = "";
        respuestas.setAttribute("style", "display:none;border:none;outline:none;");
        return;
      } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            respuestas.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            respuestas.setAttribute("style","display: block;border-top: 1px solid #272C33;border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;padding: 10px;");


         // newly Included querySelector ------------------

          var items = document.querySelectorAll("#sugerencias li");
            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
            {
              items[i].onclick = function(){
              document.getElementById('campomx').value = this.innerHTML;
              };
            }

         // EO include --------------------------------------

          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/editor/queries/paises.php?ciudad=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }

    }
```

If this is wrong please feel free to comment.